# Export Bluemix Usage

Tags: ibm-cloud

We are using Bluemix Cloud Foundry applications and need to capture billing information for reporting purposes. Is anyone aware of how you can export the billing usage from Bluemix into a .csv or any other format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't it used that much, but you could use the [`bluemix` / `bx` command with the `billing` option](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/cli/reference/bluemix_cli/bx_cli.html#bluemix_billing_org_usage) to retrieve usage and billing information per account or org. You can export it as JSON file.

The following would retrieve the usage for the org "user1@example.com" for the month of April 2017 in JSON format:

```
bx billing org-usage user1@example.com -d 2017-04 --json
```